# Use the right alignment for a buffer which is supposed to hold a struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, alignment

Suppose we have some struct, say

```
struct S
{
  double a, b;
  ~S(); // S doesn't have to be POD
};
```

Such a struct should typically have an alignment of 8, as the size of its largest contained type is 8.

Now imagine we want to declare a placeholder struct to hold the value of `S`:

```
struct Placeholder
{
  char bytes[ sizeof( S ) ];
};
```

Now we want to place it inside of another class:

```
class User
{
  char someChar;
  Placeholder holder;
public:
  // Don't mind that this is hacky -- this just shows a possible use but
  // that's not the point of the question
  User() { new ( holder.bytes ) S; }
  ~User() {  ( ( S * )( holder.bytes ) )->~S(); }
};
```

Problem is, `Placeholder` is now aligned incorrectly within `User`. Since the compiler knows that `Placeholder` is made of chars, not doubles, it would typically use an alignment of 1.

Is there a way to declare `Placeholder` with the alignment matching that of `S` in C++03? Note that `S` is not a POD type. I also understand C++11 has `alignas`, but this is not universally available yet, so I'd rather not count on it if possible.

**Update**: just to clarify, this should work for any `S` - we don't know what it contains.

Comment: With all respect, why do you need this? The placeholder seems like a bad idea.

Comment: The alignment of the struct has nothing to do with its members.  It is determined by whatever code allocated the storage for it.  You can typically count on an alignment of 8 for 32-bit code for both stack and heap but it is a strong implementation detail.  And thus not one you should ever count on.

Comment: Well, if boost does it in some way, then how does it do that?

Comment: They can do it with non standard compiler extensions and they can have some algorithm. There is an old article descring alignment calculation: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/discriminated-unions-ii/184403828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `boost::aligned_storage` may be exactly what you're looking for. It uses the union trick in such a way that your type doesn't matter (you just use `sizeof(YourType)` to tell it how to align) to make sure the alignment works out properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `union`, if you can make `S` conform to the requirements of being a member of a `union`*.

A `union` is guaranteed to have enough storage for its largest member, and aligned for its most reastrictive member.  So if we make the placeholder a union of both the raw char buffer and all the types that will actually be stored there, you will have sufficient size and correct alignment.

We will never access the members of the `union` other than the storage itself.  They are present only for alignment.

Something along these lines:

```
struct Placeholder
{
  union
  {
    char bytes [sizeof(S)];
    double alignDouble;
  };
};
```

---

- "**requirements of being a member of a union**" : Members of `union`s cannot have: non-trivial constructor, non-trivial copy constructor, non-trivial destructor, non-trivial copy-assignment operator.

Comment: Problem is, I need a solution for any possible S. That is, I don't know what S contains. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: If you can apply some restrictions on `S` such that it can be a member of a `union`, then you can use a kind a typelist and template metaprogramming to construct the alignment members of the union at compile time.

Comment: A requirement is that S need not be POD. I don't think unions would work then :(

Comment: I think the traditional semi-portable hack is to put a member of every conceivable fundamental type into a union and use that union to force (hopefully) maximal alignment.

Comment: @Casey: sounds very reasonable, but it would always force the most possible alignment, which isn't always necessary